# Input Date format issue with iOS and SQL

Tags: php, ios, iphone, sql-server, date

I have a form that has the following HTML code.  I am trying to get a date out of the form's user in yyyy-mm-dd format for insertion into SQL.  I have been using the explode function followed by parts[] in php to change mm/dd/yyyy into yyyy-mm-dd.  That process works well.  But if my user is using an iPad or iPhone the output is already in yyyy-mm-dd format and does not need to be formatted.  Any ideas on how I can streamline the process?  Thank you in advance.

```
<p>Date (mm/dd/yyyy)<br/>
    <input type="date" name="flightdate"/></p>
```

This code did not work on iPad or iPhone.  When using iPad or iPhone it doesn't output anything for $flightdate.

```
$flightdate = $_POST['flightdate'];  
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod') ||  strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')) {
$flightdate = $yyyy_mm_dd }
else { $parts = explode('/',$flightdate);
$yyyy_mm_dd = $parts[2] . '-' . $parts[0] . '-' . $parts[1];
}
```

Comment: Have you seen PHP's [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function or simply [`new DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)?

Comment: Also tried this and it doesn't echo and output. `code`$flightdate = $_POST['flightdate'];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $flightdate);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: No, use the above functions that will accept nearly any format. Let PHP do the work.

Comment: This worked;    $flightdate = $_POST['flightdate'];
$f_flightdate = date_create($flightdate);
echo date_format($f_flightdate, 'Y-m-d');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone can send the date in mm/dd/yyyy format. 
Second option - it can send just timestamp and avoid formats at all.

Comment: timestamp will not work for my purposes as I want the user to have the ability to back date their input on the date field.

Comment: What about sending the date in mm/dd/yyyy? If not, the iPhone can send the format itself as addition to the date.